# SQL query to select all forum threads but order them by the latest active thread

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently using this code to order the forum threads within my forum according to the date they were created.

```
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["forum"]);
$q = mysqli_query($con,
     "SELECT * FROM threads WHERE forum = '$e' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $offset,$rowsPerPage");
```

However, this order's the threads by their creation date rather than their activity.
How can I order the threads by their activity?

I'm thinking of something along the lines of
`SELECT * FROM threads WHERE forum = '$e' ORDER BY (replies in this thread).date DESC LIMIT 5`

Is this possible or not?

**EDIT:**
`table thread holds the inital thread data`
`table replies holds the replies`

Comment: Hard to tell without your table structure and example data.

Comment: On the information provided to date? No chance.

Comment: you need to have an updated_at column

Comment: Add a last_reply column to the forum threads table. Once someone replies to that thread, run a query that updates last_reply with a time/date stamp. then in the Query that lists the threads, ORDER it by last_reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column containing the last time a thread has been replied into your `threads` table, and then use order by this col. Don't forget to update the column on new reply.

There are ways to do it manually, but it will be far more slower than a dedicated column.

Answer (score 0):

a subselect-join will do the trick:

```
select t.* , lp.latestpost 
from threads as t 
inner join ( 
  select p.thread_id , max(p.date) as latestpost 
  from replies as p 
  group by p.thread_id
) as lp on pl.thread_id = t.id
order by lp.latestpost desc
```

Comment: left join will maybe suite you better. dont know from your question.